# Spring boot - Intellij - jsp integration

Tags: java, spring, jsp, intellij-idea

So I've got working project in Spring Boot created in IntelliJ 15 community edition. Yet, project isn't built on any archetype so there are no folders like WEB-INF as it was in Eclipse. Therefore I created my own directory in order to store .jsp pages and added path in VierResolver's prefix. Sadly, wherever the folder is placed, it still does not work. I've also tried setting prefix and suffix in application.properties, same effect. No effect.

Comment: I strongly suggest you move away from JSP especially if you are planning on doing any serious development with Spring Boot. Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines)

Comment: @geoand Move out where? To Fremarker or Velocity?

Comment: @RomanC I personally use Thymeleaf, but the features of most of them are largely the same

Comment: @geoand This is reminiscent of Krylov's fable ["The Swan, crawfish and pike"](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/swan-pike-and-crawfish/)

Comment: @RomanC Looking good :)